# Aggregate-Step multiplies following Graph-Step

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I´m having an issue in the gremlin shell, when performing the following command:

```
g.V().hasLabel('FirstLabel').aggregate('nodes')
.V().hasLabel('SecondLabel').aggregate('nodes')
.cap('nodes')
```

My aim is to aggregate all nodes matching these two labels. I know i can achieve this with different filter-steps, but i want to access the nodes with aggregate. 
The given example multiplies everything after the .V() step for each object with the firstLabel.

If I have 3 Nodes with FirstLabel and 3 Nodes with Secondlabel, the resultset gives me the first 3 nodes and the second 3 nodes each 3 times (So overall 12 Nodes).

I can however mitigate this using .limit(1) after the first aggregate, but this does not seem like a good solution.

Is there a way to perform the Graph-Step only ONCE without the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the number of current traversers to 1. This can be done using almost any reducing barrier step. Try this for example:

```
g.V().hasLabel('FirstLabel').aggregate('nodes').cap('nodes').
  V().hasLabel('SecondLabel').aggregate('nodes').cap('nodes')
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! 
But I still don´t understand why the problem occurs. A simple barrier() step instead of cap() has no effect.

I don´t understand why aggregate().cap() reduces the traverser to 1

Comment: The key is to use a reducing barrier step. `cap()`, `fold()`, `count()`, etc will all work, since they all lead to a single remaining traverser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on your use case, but it seems like this should work fine:

```
g.V().hasLabel('FirstLabel', 'SecondLabel').aggregate('nodes').cap('nodes')
```

Comment: Sure, this does give me the correct vertices, but i see a rather essential problem with multiplying the graph step for every solution found in my aggregate.  
Those labels were rather an example to produce the problem.